# fcm.onNotification() not getting called on clicking the notification when the app is in background

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ionic2, cordova-plugin-fcm

I have installed cordova-plugin-fcm and everything works fine except one little thing. When the app is in background/closed and push notification is sent from firebase, notification pops up in the devices. On clicking that notification from the tray my application starts run, but the control is not entering into fcm.onNotification().

My code in app.component.ts looks like this

```
   fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data=>{
     if(data.wasTapped){
       console.log("Received in background");
       console.log(data);
     } else {
      console.log("Received in foreground");
      console.log(data);
     };
   });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the notification should have `"click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"` for the  onNotification() to be fired, so it would not work if you are sending it from firebase console, send the notification using http reqquest, follow [Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP Protocol documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) form more insights , and i recommend [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to do it, it is also a chrome plugin.

your code should be as follow:

```
{
  "notification":{
    "title":"Notification title",
    "body":"Notification body",
    "sound":"default",
    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY", //this is needed so the onNotification() fires when notification is tapped
    "icon":"fcm_push_icon"
  },
  "data":{
    "param1":"value1",
    "param2":"value2"
  },
  "to":"/topics/topicExample"(or device token),
  "priority":"high"
}
```

references:

- [github rep](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/blob/master/README.md)
- [Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP Protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)

those two links have everything you need

good luck.

Comment: great!! it's work. just add `click_action="FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"` then function `fcm.onNotification()` is called. Thanks

Comment: @JoeSleiman do you receive any errors? did you try the above?, how are you sending the notification?

Comment: Yes i already do the same as above nothing change... And no errors.. Im trying the notification through backend

Comment: so to be clear, you are receiving the notification but it is not entering the fcm.onNotification(). or you are not receiving the notification at all ?

Comment: yes i received the notification but the fcm.onNotification doesn't trigger, i had also the local-notification plugin but i remove it, and still not working! do u recommend me to remove platform and then install it or may this damage something else

Comment: i don't think it is related to the platform, can you share the backend code that you are using to send the notification please?

Comment: not working for me :( been looking for help for a week already

Comment: I have the same problem.  I received the notification but the fcm.onNotification doesn't trigger. @JoeSleiman, con you solved this? I created this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58418159/ionic-push-notification-method-fcm-onnotification-not-work-when-app-is-open-r

Comment: @George thank you for guiding towards the solution. It works. BTW, how to collect notification data when the app is in foreground? If the ```fcm.onNotification()``` is called only when the data is tapped, is there any way to get data from the notification when the app is in foreground?

Comment: @vigmage sure you can, at the time i answered that question i was using ionic 1 project and using `FCMPlugin` plugin. to read the notification: `FCMPlugin.onNotification(function (data) {})` the data object contain a wasTapped boolean, if it is true then the data is tapped  if it is false this means the app was in foreground.