# Ionic - Push notification. Method fcm.onNotification not work when app is open/running

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4, cordova-plugin-fcm

I have a ionic app (v4). I want send push notification. I use cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated plugin and @ionic-native/fcm dependency.

In app.component.ts I have:

```
initializeApp() {
    this.plt.ready().then(() => {
        this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data)
        });
    });
}
```

I send a push notification:

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
headers: 
    Content-Type: application/json
    Authorization: key=my-key
body:
    {
      "notification":{
        "title":"My Title",
        "body":"My body",
        "sound":"default",
        "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
        "icon":"fcm_push_icon"
      },
      "data":{
        "notificationType":"MATCH_CONFIRMATION",
        "matchId":"123"
      },
      "condition":"'match_dev_confirmation_81' in topics",
      "priority":"high",
      "restricted_package_name":""
    }
```

The notification always arrives, and when I press on the notification and app is closed, the method fcm.onNotification() is called and the app opens correctly. But, when I press on the notification and the app is open/running the method fcm.onNotification() is not called.

Is this the right behavior? Is there any way that when I press the notification and the application is open, the method fcm.onNotification() is called?

Comment: Have you tried to use LocalNotifications ?