# ionic 3: in android fcm.onNotification() not getting called on clicking the notification when the app is in background

Tags: cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-fcm

In my ionic 3 app i am using [cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated](https://github.com/andrehtissot/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated) everything working fine except 1 case.

If the app is killed and when clicking on notification then onNotification() no getting called but it's getting called if the app is open.

I have check few posts but none of them worked for me :

- https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/v/7.0.0-beta.1
- [fcm.onNotification() not getting called on clicking the notification when the app is in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956891/fcm-onnotification-not-getting-called-on-clicking-the-notification-when-the-ap)
- 

Previously, I was using [cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependency-updated-apns](https://github.com/Shashank2406/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependency-updated-apns) which was working perfectly but due to UIWebView Deprecation in IOS, I need to use another option.

Here is my server payload :

```
    {
    "to" : "FCM_Token",
    
  "notification":{
    "title":"Notification title",
    "body":"Notification body",
    "sound":"default",
    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
  },
  "data":{
    "param1":"w1",
    "param2":"w1"
  },
  "priority":"high"
}
```

I am using cordova: **10.0.0 / ionic: 3.9.2 / cordova-ios: 6.1.1 / cordova-android: 9.0.0**

Anyone has an idea of how I can get onNotification() called when clicking on it if the app is killed.?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this Firebase Messaging [plugin](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging) for a while now and it works great.
It's actually the featured plugin in the Ionic [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-messaging) .

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging
npm install @ionic-native/firebase-messaging
```

It offers a different method for notifications received in the background.
You should definitely try it out.

> **onMessage(callback)**
> Called when a push message received while app is in foreground.

> **onBackgroundMessage(callback)**
> Called when a push message received while app is in background.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this plugin but somehow i am unable to get a push notification when the app is closed.
here is https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging/issues/150 same issue, do you any idea ?? @Reqven

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear solution so I ended up moving to [onesingle](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal). They provide unlimited push notification for mobile in the free plan.
I tried and it's working great!